# Second SnackBar doesn't show up in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

When I am signing out my users. First, I show them a "signing out" snackbar which is working fine. After they sign out I want to show a second snackbar to notify them about the signing out process. Then after the second snackbar I am redirecting my users to the homepage. But the second snackbar doesn't show up. I placed a delay to be sure if the users are redirected to home page before they see the snackbar but It didn't help either.

Here is the part:

```
isSigningOut 
  ? Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar( // if valid show a snackbar
    SnackBar(
      content: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          CircularProgressIndicator(),
          Text("  Signing Out...")
        ],
      ),
    )
  )
  : null;


await _auth.signOut().whenComplete(() {
  setState(() {
    isSigningOut = false;
  });
}); // Sign out by using the created auth instance


await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), (){});

Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
  content: Text(
    "Signed Out Successfully "
  ),
  duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
));


Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/home'));
```

Comment: Can you please share more of your code. You are only showing us one of the `SnackBar`s. Also, if you are triggering the second `SnackBar` from a previous view/navigation route, then it's likely the `context` you are using is no longer available and you will get an error.

Answer (score 0):

You are immediately popping the `Scaffold` which contains the second `SnackBar`. That's why it does not appear (actually it is shown but a really short amount of time).

You should show the second `SnackBar` from your home page.